# Why it doesn't recognise my selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to change the action of an **UIButton** and it gives me an exception when touching the button.

```
[grabRedeem removeTarget:self action:@selector(grabbOffer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[grabRedeem addTarget:self action:@selector(redeemOffer:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

grabbOffer and redeemOffer are IBActions that are implemented with no parameters.

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController grabbOffer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e8bf0'**

What could be the reason?

Comment: Mind the colon. `grabbOffer:` and `grabbOffer` are not the same. The former has a parameter, the later does not.

Comment: I tried without, the same error

Comment: post your grabOffer and redeemOffer methods. My guess is that you have an extra `b` on `grabbOffer:` in your selector.

Comment: - (IBAction)grabbOffer; and - (IBAction)redeemOffer; both work fine if I assign them to the button in Interface Builder; they don't return anything

Comment: Your definition does not have any parameters! grabbOffer with out a colon is correct. Same for redeemOffer

Comment: I know that, but it gives me that exception when I touch the button

Comment: I think I'm going to make two separate buttons that overlap each other and use alternate visibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to remove the colon:

```
[grabRedeem removeTarget:self action:@selector(grabbOffer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[grabRedeem addTarget:self action:@selector(redeemOffer) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

you use the semicolon when you want to use a parameter:

```
-(void)grabbOffer:(id)sender;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you function implemented with no parameters use: @selector(grabbOffer) instead @selector(grabbOffer:)